# C++ Object Passing and Returning from Functions derived from common base classes

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, polymorphism

C++ newbie here.

Let's say I have Class Fruit

Class Fruit is the base class.
Derived from Class Fruit are Class Orange, Class Apple, Class Pear, Class Grape.

I have another class, Class Hybrid, and its constructor, which requires two input parameters, both of which must be objects from Class Fruit's derived classes. These two inputs can be any two combinations of objects from the aforementioned derived classes. Class Hybrid may be inherited from Class Fruit or whatever Class that makes the solution the easiest.

Another thing, I want Class Hybrid to construct a Class Apple object then return it in a function call.  If someone could provide very basic examples of the aforementioned problems on how to do this, it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

The concepts involved are [is-a](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) versus [has-a](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a).

For example: An `Orange` **is-a** `Fruit`, but the `Hybrid` **has** two `Fruit`s.